# Shift the maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Difficult to formulate a question. I think everything is clear on the screenshot.

There are 3 columns. The percentage change in value with an offset of 1, 2, 3.
How to get the maximum value of the change?
I use Google translator. Sorry!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atoWA.png)

Comment: I don't understand the screenshot. Please rephrase the question and add your own dataset and expected result (ideally without a screenshot to make the question self-contained).

Comment: yes, i agree with @snwflk. in line 5 the value of `max_pct_change` is different (no value that is represented in `shift1`,`shift2`,or `shift3`).

Answer (score 0):

I see at your table, and to find the `max_pct_change` you can use [DataFrame.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and try the following code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'shift1':[np.nan,0.1549,-0.1012,0.0563,0.0731],
                'shift2':[np.nan,np.nan,0.0535,-0.0450,0.1295],
                'shift3':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0.1098,0.0281]})
print(df)
df['max_pct_change']=df.apply(max, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   shift1  shift2  shift3
0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  0.1549     NaN     NaN
2 -0.1012  0.0535     NaN
3  0.0563 -0.0450  0.1098
4  0.0731  0.1295  0.0281

   shift1  shift2  shift3  max_pct_change
0     NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN
1  0.1549     NaN     NaN          0.1549
2 -0.1012  0.0535     NaN          0.0535
3  0.0563 -0.0450  0.1098          0.1098
4  0.0731  0.1295  0.0281          0.1295
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: It's what I thought first, too, but your line 4 has a different `max_pct_change` than in the screenshot. Also, `shift2` in line 4 should not be negative according to the screenshot.